# How to convert String h:m to hour format?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a JSON object that looks like this,

```
{"active": "1", "opening": "11:00", "closure": "20:00"}
```

and a user input that is a String that is current time in h:m format, example:

```
17:54
```

How can I convert user's input to hour time and compare it against opening and closure. I want to do

`if(closure > input && input > opening){ 
  ... } 
 else{
   ...}`

So how do i do it?

Comment: You can compare it as is, assuming time before `10` comes with a leading zero.

Comment: Your suggestion works perfectly, post as answer and I'll mark as correct. It can be compared just as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time in the `hh:mi` format is comparable as-is.

Comment: You just have to ensure that the time is in UTC. Otherwise you might get incorrect results during DST.

Comment: @MursaleenAhmad just time in `hh:mi` format does not have notion of timezones. Otherwise, please provide an exact case (with both bounding values, the current time value and the point in time when it is happening) when what I suggested may return wrong results.

Comment: The user input is actually cellphone time that user provides, and the times I store are using the same timezone. I'm only using 2 timezones and each of the things will be based on those so yeah. Not a problem and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to convert the user-specified time string into a timestamp, and from there, it's just a comparison of numbers.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/